# Converting Gridview to RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

How do I change the below code from GridView to RadGrid?  Below is the code for my gridview:

```
protected void gv_Movie_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //get the row number of the selected row
    int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    //get the selected row
    GridViewRow row = gv_Movie.Rows[rowNo];

    //Get movie ID, which is on the 1st column of the gridview

    string movieID = row.Cells[0].Text;
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        Response.Redirect("MovieSelect.aspx?id=" + movieID);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Update")
    {
        Response.Redirect("MovieUpdate.aspx?id=" + movieID);
    }
}
```

I tried the below code and it doesn't work at all due to `e.CommandArgument`.  Any solution to this?

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());

    GridDataItem row = RadGrid1.Items[rowNo];

    string movieID = row.Cells[0].Text;
    if (e.CommandName == "Select")
    {
        Response.Redirect("movieSelect.aspx?id=" + movieID);
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        Response.Redirect("movieUpdate.aspx?id=" + movieID);
    }
}
```

Comment: By doesn't work, what do you mean?  Arguments should work the same... could you also include the markup?

Comment: Gridview>Edit Column>Add A button Field > There is no Command Arguement but in RadGrid>Edit Column> Add Grid Button Column > There is a command Arguement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
 int rowNo = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
 GridDataItem row = RadGrid1.Items[rowNo];
```

use

```
GridDataItem row = e.Item as GridDataItem;
```

Telerik automatically retrieves current row as e.Item. The rest should work the same.

Or better yet, if appropriate, try to Utilize `DataKeyNames`.

So in your markup, you will have something like:

```
<telerik:RadGrid id="grid" runat="server">
   <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="movieID">
      .....
   </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Then, you can retireve movieID like this:

```
 var row = e.Item as GridDataItem;  
 string movieID = row.GetDataKeyValue("movieID");
```

Comment: So is the plight of answering a user with no questions or answers on SO. I got your back, as it looks like a good solution! +1

Comment: @KreepN, :) yeah, that's what I've noticed, but probably it will help other people later.

Comment: @KreepN Telerik questions are often from new users, good looking out.